# How can python packages be installed for ipython located in a special location on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos, ipython, package

I have Mac OS X 10.7. I have a "default" ipython, but also a different ipython installed at a different location /sw/bin/ipython. When I install packages with pip install, though, I can't access them with the ipython at /sw/bin/ipython. How would I install packages for this other ipython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `pip`/`easy_install` binary located in `/sw/bin` to install packages. If you want this to be the default when the command is called, just put /sw/bin before /usr/bin in your .profile.